# Downcast from Base to Derive Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I am learning dynamic cast and search a lot of websites and I came to the conclusion that dynamic cast can cast from base to derive and derive to base.
However when I cast from Base to derive it gives a segmentation fault.
This is the code:

I expect from up a "from A" but it gives me a from D even after casting

```
class A
{
  public:
  virtual ~A(){} 
  virtual void print()
  {
    std::cout << "from A"<<std::endl;
  }
  };
class B:  virtual public A
{
  public:
    void print()
  {
    std::cout << "from B"<<std::endl;
  }
};       
class C: virtual public A
{
  public:
    void print()
  {
    std::cout << "from C"<<std::endl;
  }
};      
class D: public B, public C
{
  public:
    void print()
  {
    std::cout << "from D"<<std::endl;
  }
};


int main(){
    A* b = new B;
    A* c = new C;
    A* d = new D;
    A* a = new A;

    B* down = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);  // this gives me problem
    down->print();

    A* up= dynamic_cast<A*>(d); // upcasten dont print from A either
    up->print();
```

Comment: `a` is not a `B*`.  Why are you expecting it to work?

Comment: a ain't a B, you can only cast to a type that was used in the creation (or one of its bases)

Comment: `B* down = down`?

Comment: Ah now it makes sense, i thought i need a A* to upcast a pointer from derived class

Comment: @NewUser2810 `down->print();` is _undefined behavior_. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 2):

When using `dynamic_cast` to convert a pointer, you need to check the resulting pointer to see if the cast had been valid before accessing it. Accessing an invalid pointer results in undefined behavior.

```
    B* down = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    if (down == 0) {
        std::cerr << "a is not a B!\n";
    } else {
        down->print();
    }
```

You do not need to use `dynamic_cast` for "up casting". You are allowed to assign the derived to a parent. If the relationship doesn't exist, you will get a compile time error.

```
    A* up= d;
    up->print();
```

Since `print` is a virtual method, `up->print()` resolves to the implementation of the derived. However, if you wish to see the base's implementation, you can call it explicitly.

```
    d->A::print();
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHRaoMwFIbv8xRn7kZLhV1HKxh9jMFIk3QENAYTW0Zxr@6iia3QDcZYIBA@zn@@H2Vap@@MTc9SsWbgAnLZGdsL2hYTa6gxUKIrAtDDsZEMu9dZ9nagDXyWcXIdYUPOneSge6lsnDg8xwCM5RizbrCQ5xCd@q6FMsrzBQvFm8xNjfPNkPcRfN/orQ8V4Ncq8qgaM/An@Cr8f7rqZ12w1Xi1kP36qv7sq7/zIYRcEFoqlftDS7TcwREOoMQFSLYSFkh1IzyQ@kZoIKXbOiPihrqLcpR/KNpK9saosTnZFTFNfEqeIPYzB3hJQvd7f9H3S38K0oDqrFOQp1cV@fAIojFiE5o3pUX4FGEGre0G7Xp4OOjN1EJ4WpQY39g4TV8)

Comment: Mentioning _undefined behavior_ regarding the `down` case would be a good idea.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ability to cast from Base to Derived and from Derived to Base isn't the unique distinguishing feature of `dynamic_cast`. The key feature is that `dynamic_cast` performs such conversion *at runtime*, after checking that the most derived object *actually matches* (or *actually contains*) the desired target type. Which means that an error, if the conversion was unsuccessful, is also a run-time error, and that your program should be prepered to handle such errors at runtime.

What errors could those be? `dynamic_cast` may report an error either by returning a null pointer if you were casting between pointer types, say `X*` to `Y*`, or by throwing a `std::bad_cast` exception if you were casting between reference types, like `X&` to `Y&`.

Casting from `a` with the static type `A*` to `B*` could yield either valid pointer to `B` or null. The latter is exactly what happened in your example: `a` actually points to a complete object of type `A`, and there's no subobject of type `B` in it. So the cast returns null pointer which is then immediately used to call a member function `down->print()`. Any attempt to dereference the null pointer value is UB (undefined behaviour), which may well manifest as a segfault.

Protecting your program from such segfault is easy: just check that the value returned isn't null:

```
B* down = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
if (down)
{
    // Use down all you want
}
else
{
    // Report an error, skip some actions
    // or return from the function.
    // But don't use `down`!
}
```

As for printing "from D", that's because `print` method is declared virtual. It means that the implementation from the most derived class will get called even though you call it via a pointer to a base subobject.

Comment: That only answers half of the question. What is happening with `down`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it's been answered by NathanOliver before me: "`a` is not a `B*`".

Comment: @Nathan didn't write an answer, but left a comment pointing out the one half of the issue. Answers should be self contained and complete (as is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56265241/1413395)). You may put a link to [Nathan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56265039/downcast-from-base-to-derive/56265109?noredirect=1#comment99146415_56265039) to credit them for their contribution and put in the missing part.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, sorry. I'll fix my answer once I get home to a PC. However, even with a due credit, I still feel embarrassed about writing essentially the same explanation as was given above. Would you say that I'd better just delete my semi-answer?

Comment: _"Would you say that I'd better just delete my semi-answer?"_ No, better shape it to completeness, as soon you have access to your PC.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Done.